# How to calculate number of days between given months and days column from a csv file(jan 2020 to mar 2020)?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, date, datetime

If I want to count the number of days between 3 months starting from 1, Jan 2020 to 31, March 2020, and save the result in a **new column**, what is the best way to do it?

Example:-

1, Jan 2020 should be **1** and 31, March 2020 should be **91**.
so the **2** would be 2, Jan 2020
1, Feb 2020 would be **32**
2, March 2020 would be **62**

Presenting the first 20 rows which are present in the file below with the exact same column_names:
so from 1 Jan to 31 march there are total 91 days and I want that in column name countdays, so for 1 jan, which can be captured from the day column and month column, wherein month 1=jan, 2=feb and 3= march and days are associated with that so by using these 2 columns I want count of days in column name countdays

```
Code which selects columns that I want from the csv file.
y = df[['month','day','Weekdays']]
y.head(20)
```

```
OUTPUT:
   month    day Weekdays
0   1       24   4.0
1   3       13   4.0
2   2       23   6.0
3   1       19   6.0
4   1       18   5.0
5   2        8   5.0
6   2        8   5.0
7   3       11   2.0
8   2        9   6.0
9   3        6   4.0
10  1       31   4.0
11  2       21   4.0
12  3       11   2.0
13  1       31   4.0
14  2       21   4.0
15  3       11   2.0
16  1       23   3.0
17  1       18   5.0
18  2        4   1.0
19  1       14   1.0
```

Trying to generate a new column that gives me count of days using code:

```
 for m in y['month'].unique():
for d in y[y['month']==m]['day'].unique():
    y.loc[(y['month']==m) &(y['day']==d),'countdays']=datetime.datetime(2020, m, d).weekday() - datetime.datetime(2020, m, d).weekday()
```

```
OUTPUT:
         month  day Weekdays countdays
0           1   24     4.0      0.0
1           3   13     4.0      0.0
2           2   23     6.0      0.0
3           1   19     6.0      0.0
4           1   18     5.0      0.0
...       ...   ...    ...      ...
40134409    1   13     0.0      0.0
40134410    2   18     1.0      0.0
40134411    2   20     3.0      0.0
40134412    2   3      0.0      0.0
40134413    3   3      1.0      0.0
```

```
ACTUAL GOAL:
         month  day Weekdays countdays
0           1   24     4.0      24
1           3   13     4.0      74
2           2   23     6.0      54

and so on for all the rows.
```

Here in the countdays column, I want those numbers that I mentioned in the example. So for at the index 0 countdays should show **24**, index 1 should show **73** and at index 2 countdays should show **54**.

This might help: (1,Jan=1 and 31,Jan=31), (1,Feb = 32 and 29,Feb =60), (1,Mar = 61 and 31,Mar=91)

So, for Jan 1-31 days should be 1-31 and for feb 1-29 days should be 32-60 and for march 1-31 days should be 61-91.

Please let me know if the question is not clear, I'm trying my best to explain it and thank you so much for the help in advance. :)
(Feel free to make any edits or changes if something is not clear)

Comment: Nope, I referred that link but can't find a possible solution as I have to run a loop but don't know-how and with which column. (Sorry for my poor English)

Comment: The question you asked is how to calculate the number of days between two dates, and the link I provided answers that question. If you in fact have a different question, then edit the title and body of your post to ask that question instead.

Comment: Thank you, I have edited the question can you look at it again, please.

Comment: I really don't see an improvement after the edit. It's still unclear what you're asking. Please edit again to provide a sample of the output you're expecting from your sample data.

Comment: Sorry about that, I now explained everything that I have in my mind and I'm trying to do could you please give it a look and try to help me if possible, your help and kind gesture is appreciated. Thank you and please let me know if it is still not clear.

Comment: I have to admit that I still don't understand what you're asking, so I can't help. Your sample output doesn't do anything but add a new column that is filled with `0.0`, which doesn't accomplish much. I'm not going to be able to help here. I don't think you've translated what you have in your mind to something that my mind can understand.

Comment: Sounds like you're simply looking for the day of the year?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) for datetimes and then [`Series.dt.dayofyear`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.dayofyear.html):

```
df['new'] = pd.to_datetime(df[['month','day']].assign(year=2020)).dt.dayofyear

print (df)
    month  day  Weekdays  new
0       1   24       4.0   24
1       3   13       4.0   73
2       2   23       6.0   54
3       1   19       6.0   19
4       1   18       5.0   18
5       2    8       5.0   39
6       2    8       5.0   39
7       3   11       2.0   71
8       2    9       6.0   40
9       3    6       4.0   66
10      1   31       4.0   31
11      2   21       4.0   52
12      3   11       2.0   71
13      1   31       4.0   31
14      2   21       4.0   52
15      3   11       2.0   71
16      1   23       3.0   23
17      1   18       5.0   18
18      2    4       1.0   35
19      1   14       1.0   14
```

Comment: Sweet, that's exactly what I was looking for. you are a lifesaver. :)
Thank you so much.